# Extract a sub-distribution with specific characteristics

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, svm, feature-engineering

- Imagine that I have a distribution of some data. For example a distribution of natural numbers [1, 10, 45, 89, 12, 9, 4, 100]. I characterize such distribution with 2 features: the mean = 33.75 and the standard deviation sigma = 39.35.
- Now, I want to extract a sub-distribution (from [1, 10, 45, 89, 12, 9, 4, 100]) in such way that the mean of this sub-distribution is as close as possible to a given value m, and with the standard deviation as close as possible to a given value sd.

I guess it is a search problem. Do you know any fast algorithm to approximate a good solution?